# Multiplication of associated probabilities

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, probability, born-rule

If a state $\psi $ is in the $ S_{z} $ basis represented by 
$\mid\psi\rangle = c_{+}\mid z\rangle + c_{-} \mid -z\rangle$
Does the associated probabilities change when I multiply $ \psi $ by $ e^{i\phi } $?

Answer (score 0):

The spin state is given as a linear combination of spin up and spin down states. So

$$\psi=c_+| z +\rangle+c_-| z -\rangle$$

The square of the modulus of the complex coefficients $c_+$ and $c_-$ represent the probabilities of each associated base kets. When you multiply $\psi$ by a constant, the state will not change as a ket and a constant times that ket represents the same state. But the complex coefficients change.

$$e^{i\phi}\psi=e^{i\phi}c_+| z +\rangle+e^{i\phi}c_-| z -\rangle=c'_+| z +\rangle+c'_-| z -\rangle$$.

where $c'_+$ and$c'_-$ represents the new complex coeffecients.

Now, let's look at the probabilities.

Probability for the state  $|z +\rangle$ is

$$P_+=\mid c'_+\mid^2=\mid e^{i\phi}c_+\mid^2=\mid c_+\mid^2\Rightarrow\text{probability of $| z +\rangle$ state remains unchanged on multiplication of $e^{i\phi}$}$$

and that for $| z -\rangle$ is

$$P_-=\mid c'_-\mid^2=\mid e^{i\phi}c_-\mid^2=\mid c_-\mid^2\Rightarrow\text{probability of $| z -\rangle$ state remains unchanged on multiplication of $e^{i\phi}$}$$

since,  $\mid e^{i\phi}\mid^2=\mid \cos\phi+i\sin\phi\mid^2= \left(\sqrt{\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi} \right)^2=1.$

Hence the presence of the term $e^{i\phi}$ will not affect the probabilities of the states.

Comment: is it not e^{i \phi}*e^{-i \phi} since it is multiplied by a complex conjugate?

Comment: Also, is it not possible to distribute the square to cos \phi and i*sin \phi?

Comment: I don't understand what you meant

Comment: @Unnikrishnan Do you mean $| \cdot \rangle$ instead of $\langle \cdot \rangle$ ?

Comment: @Paul777 You can do $P = |c'|^2$ or $P = c'c'^* = e^{i \phi} c c^* e^{-i \phi}$. They are equivalent.

Comment: yes. both will give the same answer

Comment: Sorry, there is a slight error in the ket notation as pointed out by Asaf. I have corrected it.